NGinX bad gateway after using command to install composer
Title says it all. Prior to installing composer with a "command" in my compose.yml file
my PHP and NGinX stack was working fine. phpinfo would display on my test page. Now I just get a 502 bad gateway error.  If I comment out the "command" in my .yml file it works again.
NGinX .conf file looks like this:
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
    server_name localhost;

    root /app;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k; # increase the buffer size for PHP-FTP
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k; # increase the buffer size for PHP-FTP
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
  
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    
        # Logs for Nginx access and errors
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        
        # deny access to .htaccess/.htpasswd files
        location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

compose.yml file looks like this:
version: '3.8'

services:
    NGinX:
        image: nginx:latest
        container_name: NGinX
        hostname: NGinX
        security_opt:
            - no-new-privileges:true
        ports:
            - 6080:80/tcp
            - 6443:443/tcp
        dns:
            - 8.8.8.8
            - 1.1.1.1
        environment:
            - PUID=1000
            - PGID=100
            - TZ=Europe/London
            - UMASK=022
        volumes:
            - /volume1/docker/WebDev/NGinX/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
            - /volume1/docker/WebDev/NGinX/Logs:/var/log/nginx
            -  /volume1/docker/WebDev/WWW:/app
        restart: unless-stopped

        depends_on:
            - php


    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: PHP.dockerfile
        tty: true
        container_name: PHP
        hostname: PHP
        security_opt:
            - no-new-privileges:true
        ports:
            - 9000:9000
        environment:
            - PUID=1000
            - PGID=100
            - TZ=Europe/London
            - UMASK=022
        volumes:
            - /volume1/docker/WebDev/WWW:/app
            - /volume1/docker/WebDev/PHP/local-php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
        # run composer install command  here instead of in the dockerfile to avoid volume  mounting overwriting the  vendor folder
        command: composer run-script serve
        restart: unless-stopped

NGinX error log:
2024/07/20 12:48:32 [error] 23#23: *30 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.64.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://192.168.64.2:9000", host: "192.168.1.152:6080"
2024/07/20 12:48:32 [error] 23#23: *30 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.64.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://192.168.64.2:9000", host: "192.168.1.152:6080", referrer: "http://192.168.1.152:6080/"

What makes you think this problem is related to Composer itself?

Hi Nico, it may not be composer however if I comment out the "command: composer run-script serve" everything works as it should I.e. php will pass scripts fine and I don't get an NGinx 502 error page.

The error messages in your Nginx log indicate that Nginx is unable to connect to the upstream server (FastCGI server) at 192.168.64.2:9000. The Connection refused error suggests that the upstream server is not running or not accepting connections on the specified IP and port.
Here are some steps to troubleshoot and resolve this issue:

Check if the upstream server is running:

Ensure that the FastCGI server (e.g., PHP-FPM) is running on the specified IP and port.
You can use a command like netstat or ss to check if the port is open and the server is listening:
netstat -tulnp | grep 9000


Alternatively, use telnet or nc to test connectivity:
telnet 192.168.64.2 9000




Check the upstream server configuration:

Verify that the FastCGI server is configured to listen on 192.168.64.2:9000.
Check the configuration file (e.g., for PHP-FPM, it might be /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf or similar).


Check firewall and security settings:

Ensure that there are no firewall rules blocking the connection between Nginx and the FastCGI server.
Check if SELinux or AppArmor is restricting the connection.


Verify Nginx configuration:

Ensure the upstream configuration in your Nginx configuration file is correct.
Here’s an example of a correct FastCGI upstream configuration:
upstream backend {
    server 192.168.64.2:9000;
}

server {
    listen 6080;
    server_name 192.168.1.152;

    location / {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass backend;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/your/script.php;
    }
}




Check logs for more details:

Review the logs of the FastCGI server to see if there are any errors or warnings that might explain why it’s not accepting connections.



By following these steps, you should be able to identify and resolve the issue preventing Nginx from connecting to the upstream server. If you need further assistance, please provide more details about your configuration and environment.

Hi Indian2020, I'm going to try your suggestions as soon as I'm back in front of the PC. However your answer still does not explain that if I comment out the "command" in the yml file the error disappears and the server has no problem connecting to fastcgi. using the same ip and port. Wouldn't that suggest it's working?

Hi Indian2020, I tried your suggestions and it seems fastcgi is not running in my nginx container! My nginx -conf config is in my question what other info do you need to help me figure this one out?
